# jQuery: pushing array of values in serializeArray

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these:

```
<input class="orders" name="orders[]" value="1">
<input class="orders" name="orders[]" value="2">
<input class="orders" name="orders[]" value="3">
```

I try add values of `orders` to an `serializeArray` in JQUERY.

I do this:

```
var datastring = $("#form1").serializeArray();

var orders = [];
$('input.orders').each(function() {
       orders.push($(this).val()); 
 });
 datastring.push({name: "orders", value: orders});
```

in server side,(when I convert it into a json format) I want `["1","2","3"]`

but now only I get a string:1,2,3

I try change it to:

```
datastring.push({name: "orders[]", value: orders});
```

Now when I convert it to json string (in server side) I get this:

```
["1,2,3"]
```

can please tell me my mistake?

Comment: `["1","2","3"].join(',')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is an array with objects that have the same name

```
var datastring = $("#form1").serializeArray();

$('input.orders').each(function() {
    datastring.push({name: this.name, value: this.value}); 
});
```

And make you sure you use the correct class, remove the brackets

```
<input class="orders" name="orders[]" value="1">
<input class="orders" name="orders[]" value="2">
<input class="orders" name="orders[]" value="3">
```

This will give you an array looking like

```
[
    {
        "name": "orders[]",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "orders[]",
        "value": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "orders[]",
        "value": "3"
    }
]
```

jQuery will in turn parse that array to the string `orders[]=1&orders[]=2&orders[]=3` when submitted, which is what most serverside languages that parse `[]` as form groups expect, both the key and the value for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Just try joining the array:

Example snippet for reference:

```js
var datastring = [];
datastring.push({
  name: "orders",
  value: ['1', '2', '3'].join(',')
});
console.log(datastring[0]["value"])
```